# Two circle intersection: help on understanding a specific explanation

Tags: geometry, circles

As someone with basic algebra knowledge, I am having trouble understanding Paul Bourke's explanation on "Intersection of two circles" on this [page](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/).

The specific part that I don't understand is where the last three equations come from:

1) $P_2 = P_0 + a \cdot \dfrac{ P_1 - P_0 } {d}$

2) $x_3 = x_2 \pm h \cdot\dfrac{ y_1 - y_0 }{d}$

3) $y_3 = y_2 \mp h\cdot  \dfrac{ x_1 - x_0} {d}$

Can anyone help shed some light on how they are derived? Or at the very least point me in the right direction?

Comment: For the first one, consider $P_2$ as starting at $P_0$ and then traveling a portion of the distance from $P_0$ to $P_1$.  Specifically this fraction of it: $\frac{a}{d}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All segment lengths are considered as positive. You have to add in the negative signs somewhere when necessary.

[image]

$x_3 = x_2 + k$

$= x_2 + h \sin \theta$ ... [from the smallest triangle]

$= x_2 + h \cdot \dfrac {y_1 – y_0}{d}$ ... [from the largest triangle]

It is part of the statement #2. Other statements can be proved in a similar fashion.

Answer (score -1):

In eq. 1) the second term is a vector distance (P1-P0) which is then factorized by a/d so that P2 lies in the line connecting P0 and P1 at a distance a/d starting at P0. This equation is not used for calculations anyway.

To better understand equation 2 you could draw the axis x and y in anyway you want and you'll find out that (y1-y0)/d corresponds to sin(θ) where θ is the angle between the line P0P1 and the x axis.

h⋅(y1−y0)/d = h.sin(θ)

The angle θ happens to be also the same angle between the line P2P3 and the y axis which you use to derive the x component of P3 by computing h.sin(θ).

Eq. 3 can be explained in the same way as eq. 2, but in this case (x1−x0)/d corresponds to cos(θ).

It would be clearer by looking at a drawing but hopefully you'll be able to draw it yourself after this explanation.