# Pythagoras and Circles intersetion

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

I am trying to learn computational geometry(basics) and here i am not understanding how this person got $$P2 = P0 + a ( P1 - P0 ) / d.$$ I tried to solve many times but i get wrong result.Can someone please explain me how he did this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, what you posted explains it thoroughly.  At what point are you confused.

Comment: How he gets d in division? The rest i understand that it is a convex combination but i can't get  d  in denominator , in this equation $P2 = P0 + a ( P1 - P0 ) / d$.

Comment: That's just saying that $P_2$ is $\frac a d$ of the distance between $P_0$ and $P_1$.  If $P_i = (x_i, y_i)$ and for the three points then $(x_2,y_2) = (x_0+ \frac ad (x_1 - x_0), y_0 + \frac ad (y_1 - y_0))$.  Or in other words $P_2 = P_0 + \frac ad (P_1 - P_0)$.  It's a given.  A self-evident truth.  The equation of a point on a line.

Comment: See my answer to the question similar to this one in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409951/two-circle-intersection-help-on-understanding-a-specific-explanation/1410377#1410377